# how to enter one more level in the leafnode in Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am preparing a `TreeView` with `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. it contains multiple levels in it. however, the data structure at all the levels are of same type.
I have a property in the data structure called `isNodeAleaf`. I set this property to true to all leaf level elements.

I have a `HiearchicalDataTemplate` set for populating the tree as shown below.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleChildren}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Width>250</ColumnDefinition.Width>
         </ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition/>
               <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RiskName}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
         </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

it populates the tree as expected. Now, I need to attach to each and every leaf a few more attributes.
These attributes are mainly the elements such as marking a leafnode so that at the later stage, it can be considered. this helps in a way that out of so many elements in the tree, we get to know which are important one.
We can have several other properties in future to attached to each and every leaf elements.

```
1
-|2
  -|3
    -|4 => leaf node
      -| prop1 -| prop2 -| prop3 -| prop4   
    -|5
      -| prop1 -| prop2 -| prop3 -| prop4   
    -|6
      -| prop1 -| prop2 -| prop3 -| prop4
```

now my question is how can I modify my `HiearchicalDataTemplate` in order to get the  visual style shown above.

I would appreciate if anyone in the community can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Making the properties of a Node appear as child node of a node takes a little work. The simplest way is to enumerate the properties into a list as the TreeView only works with lists of object.

expose another IEnumerable property. The property returns a single object that contains a string representation of the properties.

I have created a simple example below to show what I mean. In it, I use reflection to create a new node to display the property information and I have exposed that dummy item via a property of type IEnumerable. I am also using a Style and a DataTemplate to mimic an HierarchicalDataTemplate.

In my example, the code behind is

```
namespace StackOverflow._21906388
{
    public class MyNode
    {
        public MyNode()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>();
            Property1 = "P1";
            Property2 = "P1";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsLeafNode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Property 1")]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Property 2")]
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<MyNode> Items { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MyNode> Properties
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new List<MyNode>();

                if (IsLeafNode)
                {
                    var nameBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                    this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>() != null).ToList()
                        .ForEach(p => nameBuffer.Append(string.Format(" - | {0}: {1}", p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName, p.GetValue(this))));
                    list.Add(new MyNode() { Name = nameBuffer.ToString() });
                }
                return list;
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitialiseData();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyNode> Items { get; set; }

        public void InitialiseData()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
            {
                new MyNode
                {
                    Name = "one",
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
                    {
                        new MyNode { Name = "one", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "two", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
                    }
                },
                new MyNode
                {
                    Name = "two",
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
                    {
                        new MyNode { Name = "one", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "two", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
                    }
                },
                new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The windows xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._21906388.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._21906388"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:MyNode}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>        

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLeafNode}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Properties}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Items}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can copy this code into an empty WPF application project to see it run.

You can change the way (and when) the dummy node gets generated, insert the dummy node into the child list, and then implement a HierarchicalDataTemplate to traverse the object graph instead of the .

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you really compile your code? Compilation fails?

Comment: There were some major problems with your code. the compilation and secondly, leafnodes were not horizontally oriented. I have changed it and posted an answer below. However, I used majorly your code and modified it.

Comment: Yes, I just created a new project and copied the code from this page and it ran. The only manual process required was to add the missing using statements. I am sorry I misunderstood your requirements around the leaf nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. you can check my solution if you wish too and mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The are a couple of ways to do this but the simplest way is to use an ItemsControl and insert a horizontally orientated StackPanel as its ItemsPanel. For Example, in your HierarchicalDataTemplate, insert the ItemsControl in the 2nd row of the Grid that has the TextBlock like so.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RiskName}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}" Visibility="{Binding Path=isNodeAleaf, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Grid>
```

You will have to include a BooleanToVisibilityConverter resource to only show the Properties list for a leaf.

If you find that you have to many items for the StackPanel, replace it with a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Regarding the display of the properties, just template each item via the ItemTemplate property of the ItemsControl.

***This answer assumes you want the properties to display in the same node as the leaf element. If you want the properties to display as a child node of the leaf element, let me know via comment and I will post an answer for that scenario.***

I hope this helps.

Comment: The only thing I intend to achieve is to select these properties and leaf element independently.

Comment: Just for clarifications, what are these properties in ItemSource for?

Comment: You did not mention how your were storing the properties on the leaf nodes. I assumed, since you were going to add more, that it would be some kind of dictionary. I can show you how to achieve the 'Properties' node but I need to know if they are properties on the node object itself or if they are stored in some form of collection.

Comment: These properties are , as of now, the class properties and are independent. they are not stored in a dictionary or in any kind of collection.

Comment: I have added another answer to cover the class properties. Instead of using a HierarchicalDataTemplate, I have used a Style and a DataTemplate to traverse the object graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:MyNode}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLeafNode}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Properties}" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Items}" />

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code where all display names are captured.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyNode
    {
        public MyNode()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>();
            Property1 = "P1";
            Property2 = "P1";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsLeafNode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Property 1")]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Property 2")]
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<MyNode> Items { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MyNode> Properties
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new List<MyNode>();


                if (IsLeafNode)
                {
                    var nameBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                    Type type = new MyNode().GetType();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in type.GetProperties())
                    {
                        DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pInfo, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));

                        if (attr != null)
                        {
                            list.Add(new MyNode() { Name = attr.DisplayName.ToString() });

                        }
                    }

                }
                return list;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

the mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitialiseData();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyNode> Items { get; set; }

        public void InitialiseData()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
            {
                new MyNode
                {
                    Name = "one",
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
                    {
                        new MyNode { Name = "one", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "two", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
                    }
                },
                new MyNode
                {
                    Name = "two",
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyNode>
                    {
                        new MyNode { Name = "one", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "two", IsLeafNode = true },
                        new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
                    }
                },
                new MyNode { Name = "three", IsLeafNode = true }
            };
        }
    }
```